# bad spacing between macro and real rendering

Tags: macros, spacing, line-spacing, renewcommand

Here is a capture of the current rendering I get :

[image: bad and no symmetric spacing]

I am obliged to set a "`\,`" after the `GC$_{\text{ph}}$` and `WL` to have a little spacing after these symbol to not interfer with classical text, that is to say :

```
\newcommand{\GCp}{GC$_{\text{ph}}$\,}
\newcommand{\WL}{WL\,}
```

and the Latex source :

```
Here after a triplot showing the 2D joint distribution with individually the \GCp and \WL probes and their simple combination.
```

As you can see, this is not symmetric and even I put "`\,`" on each side in `\newcommand`, this is not pretty.

I am on overleaf.

If someone could tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: you need `\ ` after a command name to generate a space in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand why you want to type `\WL` to print "WL"! Simply type "WL". For the other one, take
`\newcommand{\GCp}{$ \text{GC}_{\text{ph}} $~}`

Comment: What of OP wants to type `\GCp` at the end of a sentence, followed by a period?

Comment: Oh yes! My mistake. David Carlaisle's comment is enough then I guess.